# How to use 'extern' to access a function from another file in C

Tags: c, function, extern

I've a function declared in a file in a directory, say, abc. main/abc/getcm.c

```
XAPUBLIC int get_cm_name(cm_name)
```

I've to use this function in another directory, say def. main/def/takecm.c

```
status = get_cm_name(cm_name)
```

How can i access this function 'get_cm_name' in 'def' directory using extern. I understand that i can use a header file under 'main' directory to declare this function. Is there an alternative of doing it using extern function.

Comment: isn't it like functions, unless defined `static` are by default defined with `extern`?

Comment: google for "forward declaration"

Comment: XAPUBLIC is not a standard term — is this part of the XA protocol?  Is cm_name a type name?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the compile process. You can provide search paths for libraries and header files. However, in your case you simply have your *source* files in separate directories. In that case, during compile, you simply need to provide the complete path to each of your required source files so they can be compiled to object and linked into the final executable.

Comment: So how can i provide the complete path to both of the source files. I understand how to add header files using '#include'.

Comment: I think i got the answer in this discussion[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c?rq=1]